# Parent Pick Whip Not Showed On Effect Transform Keyframing

Tags: after-effects, after-effects-expressions, motion, tracking

I wanted to parent the effect transform expression to the tracking motion (null object)

When I saw the tutorials.. it showed me to click and drag the pick whip, but on my after effects there are no pick whip on the side of transform value

[image: Not Showed]

Answer (score 1):

Expressions aren't parented. They use the same kind of widget but it's not the one in the parent column.

You need to enable expressions on the property by <kbd>alt</kbd>-clicking the stopwatch. Now you'll see the expressions pickwhip, as well as the dropdown with the expressions menu and so on. You'll know that expressions are applied because the value will turn red.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you arrived at this question because you have a whole layer and not just an expression but still can't find the pick whip option, try right-clicking the tool bar, going to "Columns" and enabling "Parent". [Video demonstration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aEeucj7jq80).